# Could you recommend best practices for developing distributed applications using WPF over a large data volume?

Tags: wpf, architecture, distributed

We're starting to develop a distributed client server application using WPF.
I'm looking for best practices that can answer the following requirements:

1. There can be multiple sources of data that can be combined on the client side.
2. Server side data can be decorated with new business data.
3. Application should be able to handle very large volume of data (hunders of thousands of records in the grid).
4. Multiple clients should be synced. i.e. if a client changes an entity that is currently displayed in another client - the other client should be notified of this.

I'd appreciate any reference to books / articles / blogs / samples that discuss all or part of the issues.

I'm looking more into MVVM + domain model.

Thanks for your help & time
Ron

Answer (score 1):

I may request you to reiterate the need of your (3) point. Does the application logic really need all that large volume of data to the client side? If you can reduce that to the minimum and have the DataGrid stores the states of the scroll position/filtering/searching, then you can always retrieve the next set of results from the server pretty fast on a pagination or on a scroll trigger. Of course this is way more work both at client side and server side than doing a Select * from Table as WCF result and bind that to a DataGrid :). My point is that you may need to think about the Server side Data-virtualization instead of client so that you won't deliver unwanted data which user will never look at.

Think about the Google search results, browser gets just a small fraction of those million results but server knows the context. So I would recommend you to explore that idea and reduce the client side complexities and work. Make the data across the network as minimum as possible, and do calls to server as asynchronous chunks of small amount of data. I am sure you will get far better results.

(4) You can use a Duplex binding or some lazy-thread polling mechanism depends on how fast you need the updates. again those update channel messaging should be as small as possible to improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Do you have some more detailed reference (article / blog / sample) to show your ideas (or part of them at least)  Thanks again, Ron